# Is force corresponding to surface tension conservative?

Tags: forces, work, fluid-statics, surface-tension, conservative-field

Suppose you have a structure like shown in the figure. Is the force corresponding to surface tension, $2\gamma l$, conservative? If it is **not** then by work-energy theorem, for the system consisting of the jumper (the moving part) and the fluid film we can write $W_T+W_{ST}$$=\Delta E=$$\gamma \Delta A$, where $W_T,\ W_{st}$ are, respectively, work done by $T$ and force exerted by the liquid surface on the jumper. Is this correct?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should just be $W_T = \Delta E =\gamma \Delta A$

as the $W_{ST}$ is from a force acting on the person and not the water film.

Comment: WET stands for work-energy theorem.

Comment: According to WET change in mechanical energy of system equals work done by all the none conversation forces on the system. The forces can be external or internal. My question is if force by the liquid film on the jumper is non-conservative. If it is then by WET I can write that $W {st}+W_{T}=\Delta E$ since the slider is also in part of my system including the soap film.